# Laravel 7 how to redirect back if there is an error validation to boostrap modal dialog window and stay in modal if click submit

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-modal, laravel-7

Please help, I want my modal to be open if there is a validation error, when click submit modal will still appear, I need help I've tried several times but it still fails. Sory for my bad english

This is my view

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card card-header-actions">
            <div class="card-header">List Jenis Sparepart
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modaltambah">Tambah
                    Jenis Sparepart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="datatable">
                {{-- SHOW ENTRIES --}}
                <div id="dataTable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper dt-bootstrap4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                            <div class="dataTables_length" id="dataTable_length">
                                <label>Show
                                    <select name="dataTable_length" aria-controls="dataTable"
                                        class="custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm">
                                        <option value="10">5</option>
                                        <option value="25">10</option>
                                        <option value="50">25</option>
                                        <option value="100">50</option>
                                    </select> entries
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                            <div id="dataTable_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
                                <label>Search:
                                    <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder=""
                                        aria-controls="dataTable">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @if(session('messageberhasil'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                            {{ session('messageberhasil') }}
                            <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable" id="dataTable" width="100%"
                                cellspacing="0" role="grid" aria-describedby="dataTable_info" style="width: 100%;">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr role="row">
                                        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1"
                                            colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending"
                                            aria-label="Name: activate to sort column descending"
                                            style="width: 30px;">No</th>
                                        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1"
                                            colspan="1" aria-label="Position: activate to sort column ascending"
                                            style="width: 230px;">Jenis Sparepart</th>
                                        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1"
                                            colspan="1" aria-label="Position: activate to sort column ascending"
                                            style="width: 200px;">Keterangan</th>
                                        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1"
                                            colspan="1" aria-label="Actions: activate to sort column ascending"
                                            style="width: 77px;">Actions</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @forelse ($jenissparepart as $item)
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row" class="small">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
                                        <td>{{ $item->jenis_sparepart }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $item->keterangan }}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-datatable  mr-2" type="button"
                                                data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modaledit-{{ $item->id_jenis_sparepart }}">
                                                <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <form action="{{ route('jenis-sparepart.destroy',$item->id_jenis_sparepart) }}" method="POST" class="d-inline">
                                                @csrf
                                                @method('delete')
                                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-datatable ">
                                                        <i class="fas fa-trash"></i></i>
                                                    </button>
                                            </form>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @empty
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="7" class="tex-center">
                                            Data Kosong
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforelse
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
                            <div class="dataTables_info" id="dataTable_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">
                                Showing 1 to 10 of 10 entries</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
                            <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="dataTable_paginate">
                                <ul class="pagination">
                                    <li class="paginate_button page-item previous disabled" id="dataTable_previous">
                                        <a href="#" aria-controls="dataTable" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0"
                                            class="page-link">Previous</a></li>
                                    <li class="paginate_button page-item active"><a href="#"
                                            aria-controls="dataTable" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0"
                                            class="page-link">1</a></li>
                                    <li class="paginate_button page-item "><a href="#" aria-controls="dataTable"
                                            data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0" class="page-link">2</a></li>
                                    <li class="paginate_button page-item "><a href="#" aria-controls="dataTable"
                                            data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0" class="page-link">3</a></li>
                                    <li class="paginate_button page-item "><a href="#" aria-controls="dataTable"
                                            data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0" class="page-link">4</a></li>
                                    <li class="paginate_button page-item "><a href="#" aria-controls="dataTable"
                                            data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0" class="page-link">5</a></li>
                                    <li class="paginate_button page-item "><a href="#" aria-controls="dataTable"
                                            data-dt-idx="6" tabindex="0" class="page-link">6</a></li>
                                    <li class="paginate_button page-item next" id="dataTable_next"><a href="#"
                                            aria-controls="dataTable" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0"
                                            class="page-link">Next</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {{-- MODAL Tambah -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}}
    <div class="modal fade" id="Modaltambah" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Tambah Jenis Sparepart</h5>
                    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                            aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                </div>
                <form action="{{ route('jenis-sparepart.store') }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="small mb-1" for="jenis_sparepart">Jenis Sparepart</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="jenis_sparepart" type="text" id="jenis_sparepart"
                                placeholder="Input Jenis Sparepart" value="{{ old('jenis_sparepart') }}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="small mb-1" for="keterangan">Keterangan</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="keterangan" type="text" id="keterangan"
                                placeholder="Masukan Keterangan" value="{{ old('keterangan') }}"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {{-- Validasi Error --}}
                    @if (count($errors) > 0)       
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <strong>Error</strong>
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="Submit">Tambah</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {{-- MODAL EDIT -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}} 
    @forelse ($jenissparepart as $item)
        <div class="modal fade" id="Modaledit-{{ $item->id_jenis_sparepart }}" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
            aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Tambah Jenis Sparepart</h5>
                        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                                aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                    </div>
                    <form action="{{ route('jenis-sparepart.update', $item->id_jenis_sparepart) }}" method="POST">
                        @method('PUT')
                        @csrf
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="small" for="jenis_sparepart">Jenis Sparepart</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="jenis_sparepart" type="text" id="jenis_sparepart"
                                    value="{{ $item->jenis_sparepart }}" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="small" for="keterangan">Keterangan</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="keterangan" type="text" id="keterangan"
                                    value="{{ $item->keterangan }}" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="Submit">Tambah</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @empty

    @endforelse
```

This is my controller:

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Inventory\Masterdata;

use App\Model\Inventory\Jenissparepart;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Inventory\Jenissparepartrequest;
use App\Http\Requests\Inventory\Merksparepartrequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MasterdatajenissparepartController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $jenissparepart = Jenissparepart::get();

        // Cek nilai merksparepart -> array
        // dd($jenissparepart);

        return view('pages.inventory.masterdata.jenissparepart', compact('jenissparepart'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Jenissparepartrequest $request)
    {
        $jenissparepart = new Jenissparepart;
        $jenissparepart->jenis_sparepart = $request->jenis_sparepart;
        $jenissparepart->keterangan = $request->keterangan;

        $jenissparepart->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with('messageberhasil', 'Data Jenis Sparepart Berhasil ditambahkan');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Jenissparepartrequest $request, $id_jenis_sparepart)
    {
        $jenissparepart = Jenissparepart::findOrFail($id_jenis_sparepart);
        $jenissparepart->jenis_sparepart = $request->jenis_sparepart;
        $jenissparepart->keterangan = $request->keterangan;

        $jenissparepart->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id_jenis_sparepart)
    {
        $jenissparepart = Jenissparepart::findOrFail($id_jenis_sparepart);
        $jenissparepart->delete();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

This is my validation in formrequest

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Inventory;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class Merksparepartrequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'kode_merk' => 'required',
        'merk_sparepart' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

}

thank you I really appreciate if anyone answers this for my college assignments

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any validation procedure implemented in your store function in your controller. Where do you actually validate the data here?

Comment: So much code! It would be easier to help if you can create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't see any Javascript? A normal HTML form submission will open a new page, this is standard. If you want instead to stay on the same page, with the same modal open, you need to submit the form with Javascript, and then display any validation errors on the modal using JS.  *OR* open a new page, and use JS to automatically re-open the modal to show errors.